# applicationQueuePlayer establishConnectionIfNeeded timeout

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-music, apple-musickit

Trying to play apple music with **MPMusicPlayerController**.applicationMusicPlayer it's showing 
error

> <[SDKPlayback] applicationQueuePlayer _establishConnectionIfNeeded
>   timeout [ping did not pong]>

on iOS 13.4
but same code run on iOS 13.3 working perfectly 
is that iOS 13.4 bug or do we need to change something?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm still getting this error in TvOs 14.5

Comment: i solved the issue by adding region code (ex - when try to get the music id from api call use local region i m from indi i use IN & also check region settings on TV preferences it  has to be same region otherwise issue never get sove)

Comment: But do you use applicationMusicPlayer or did you switch to systemMusicPlayer? I would like to use the applicationMusicPlayer but even with the correct country code I get this error. The systemMusicPlayer works btw.